# Hibernate - compare DateTime field with Restrictions.like

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

I have a `createDateTime` field with `Date` dataType in my entity class and hibernate generated a column with `datetime` type in the mysql table. Now, I need to compare `createDateTime` field with **values without seconds**. In fact, one user can enter for example `2015-01-01 12:10` in the search field and I want to show the record that has `2015-01-01 12:10:10` `crateDateTime` as a result. I know this is possible with flat query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE crateDateTime LIKE "2015-01-01 12:10 %"
```

But I don't know how I can do this via hibernate.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
data = formatter.parse("2015-01-01 12:10");

//This returned null.
Criterion crtmp = Restrictions.like("createDateTime", data);

//This returned ClassCastException. Because second argument must have "Date" dataType not "String"
Criterion crtmp = Restrictions.like("createDateTime", data + "%");
```

Comment: I doubt that using like on a timestamp is a good idea. I think you should use between instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Date variable e.g. `createDateTimePlusOneMinute`,  than find a time range between your `createDateTime` and `createDateTimePlusOneMinute`, using the following restrictions

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("createDateTime", createDateTime));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("createDateTime", createDateTimePlusOneMinute));
```

Answer (score 0):

// datetime comparison

```
       Select c from Customer c where c.date<{d '2000-01-01'}
```